# Passing props, state and [this] values to a utility file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best way/practice to pass props, state and [this] values to a utility file?

My utils file is just 3 functions I export. Please check the example code I've provided. I am just passing the [this] directly to the function, just seems a bit weird like I'm doing the wrong thing. Just wondering if there's a better way when dealing with files that aren't components

Thanks

```
// index.js
utils.saveData(data, this);

// utils.js
const saveData = (data, _this) => {
  const { props } = _this;
  fetch(`https:/someURL/update`, {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
  .then(() => {
    props.history.push({
      pathname: `/thankyou`
    });
  })
  .catch(() => {
    // my want set state here or use [this]
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> Just wandering if there's a better way when dealing with files that aren't componenets

**Use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)**.

Hooks add some stateful logic and can perform side effects. Also reusable and should only be used within functional components. No need for `this`.

With hooks, you can do something like:

```
const useHistory = (props) => {
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([])
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    function doFetch() {
      fetch('https://someURL/update', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(props.data)
      })
        .then(() => {
          setHistory(history => ([
            ...history,
            {
               pathname: `/thankyou`
            }
          ]);
        })
        .catch((error) => setError(error));
    }

    doFetch()

  }, [props.data])

  return { history, error }
};

function SomeApp() {
  const { history, error } = useHistory({ data: postParams })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the simple responsibility principle, your utility function should do only one thing don't mix and match.

I would recommend you use `async/await` but if you can't use callbacks

```js
// utils.js
const saveData = (data, cb) => {
  fetch(`https:/someURL/update`, {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
  .then(() => cb())
  .catch(cb);
};
```

In your main file

```js
//Component.js
const callback = (err) => {
   if(err) {
      // I want set state here or use [this]
   } else {
      this.props.history.push({
        pathname: `/thankyou`
      });
   }
}

utils.saveData(data, callback);
```

Now the util has no idea where the data is coming from, the only thing the `saveData` utility will do call api and said its success or failure.

Comment: hey, thanks, i could use async/await but don't i need to use fetch anyway if i use async/await... what are the advantages? how would you suggest i go about it?